# Turning a list/sequence of combinator parsers into a single one

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have a list of values from which I can construct a list of parsers, that depend on these values by mapping (see example). Then what I want to do is turn the list of parsers into a single parser by concatenation.

One possibility is using `foldLeft` and `~`:

```
parsers.foldLeft(success(Nil)){case (ps,p) => rs ~ p ^^ {case xs ~ x => x ::xs}} ^^ (_.reverse)
```

### Is this efficient?

I don't know how combinator parsers work; will there be a call stack with depth of length of the list? Thus may I run into SO errors for very long concatenations?

### Better way

Is there a different way that is more readable?

### Example

Suppose you have a file with two lines. The first line contains n integers x_1 to x_n. The second line contains contains x_1 + x_2 + ... x_n integers that belong to groups according to the first line. I want to take the sequence of integers from the first line and create n parsers p_1 to p_n where p_i parses x_i integers.

Suppose I have the list of integers `l = List(1,2,3)` from the first line. For each integer `n` I create a parser that parses `n` integers: `parsers = l.map(repN(_,integer))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're describing (and what you've more or less reinvented in your implementation with `foldLeft` and `~`) is essentially Haskell's [`sequence`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html) for monads (really you only need an applicative functor, but that's irrelevant here). `sequence` takes a list of monadic values and returns a monadic list of values. `Parser` is a monad, so `sequence` for `Parser` would change a `List[Parser[A]]` into a `Parser[List[A]]`.

[Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) gives you `sequence`, but off the top of my head I don't know if there's a nice way to get the necessary `Applicative` instance for `Parser`. Fortunately you can roll your own pretty easily (I'm directly translating [the Haskell definition](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence)):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object parser extends RegexParsers {
  val integer = """\d+""".r

  val counts = List(1, 2, 3)
  val parsers = counts.map(repN(_, integer))

  val line = parsers.foldRight(success(Nil: List[List[String]])) {
    (m, n) => for { x <- m ; xs <- n } yield (x :: xs)
  }

  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(line, s)
}
```

This gives us `List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))` for `parser("1 2 3 4 5 6")`, as desired.

(Note that I'm using `RegexParsers` here as a convenient complete example, but the approach works more generally.)

What's going on might be a little clearer if we desugar the `for` comprehension:

```
val line = parsers.foldRight(success(Nil: List[List[String]])) {
  (current, acc) => current.flatMap(x => acc.map(x :: _))
}
```

We can write `flatMap` as `into` and `map` as `^^`:

```
val line = parsers.foldRight(success(Nil: List[List[String]])) {
  (current, acc) => current into (x => acc ^^ (x :: _))
}
```

This isn't too far from your formulation, except that we're using a right fold instead of reversing and aren't building up and breaking down the `~`s.

---

About efficiency: Both of our implementations are going to result in unpleasant call stacks. In my experience this is just a fact of life with Scala's parser combinators. To quote [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011141/scala-parser-combinators-vs-antlr-java-generated-parser/6011722#6011722), for example:

> Scala's parser combinators aren't very efficient. They weren't
>   designed to be. They're good for doing small tasks with relatively
>   small inputs.

My `sequence`-y approach addresses the "more readable" part of your question, and is almost certainly the cleanest way to solve the problem with Scala's parser combinators. It's marginally more efficient than your implementation, and should be fine for a few thousand groups or so. If you need to handle more than that, you'll have to look outside of `scala.util.parsing.combinator`. I'd recommend something like the following:

```
def parse(counts: Seq[Int], input: String): Option[Seq[Seq[Int]]] = {
  val parsed = try {
    Some(input.split(" ").map(_.toInt))
  } catch {
    case _ : java.lang.NumberFormatException => None
  }

  parsed.flatMap { ints =>
    if (ints.length != counts.sum) None
    else Some(counts.foldLeft((Seq.empty[Seq[Int]], ints)) {
      case ((collected, remaining), count) => {
        val (m, n) = remaining.splitAt(count)
        (m.toSeq +: collected, n)
      }
    }._1.reverse)
  }
}
```

No guarantees, but on my system it doesn't overflow on a line with 100k integer groups.

---

Comment: Can you say something about the depth of the call stack during runtime? Looking into the source of Parser, things like `repN` are implemented using a while loop. Could I get stack overflow for very long sequences using my or your implementation?

Comment: @ziggystar: I've edited my answer to address the issue of the call stack depth.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `RegexParsers` (in `scala.util.parsing.combinator`)?  Then you can use regular expressions as parsers, which will compute very fast and be easy to write.

For example, if you are using parser combinators to parse an AST for simple arithmatic, you might use regular expressions to interpret tokens that refer to objects so you can parse expressions like `appleList.size + 4`.

Here is a rather trivial example, but it shows how regular expressions can be combined by parser combinators.

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  val regex1 = """[abc]*""".r
  val regex2 = """[def]*""".r
  val parse = regex1 ~ regex2

  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(parse, s)
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can help me. Can you solve my example with a regex parser?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not fully understand your question.  Are you able to reword your example?

Comment: As another note, I think parser combinators use recursive descent.  There is a combinator `~!` that avoids backtracking and so it parses only LL(1) grammars.  This may improve the efficiency of what you are doing.

Comment: As I understand only alternatives  (`|` and `|||`) do backtrack. But I don't know either. And I'll add a bit of explanation to the example.

Comment: Disjunctions backtrack depending on if `~` or `~!` was used.  For example, `("a"~"b")|("a"~"c")` will parse "ab" and "ac" but `("a"~!"b")|("a"~!"c")` will not backtrack and parse "ac".  I found [Martin Odersky's chapter on parser combinators](http://lamp.epfl.ch/teaching/foundations_of_software/docs/combinator_parsing.pdf) to be the most helpful , although I could clearly understand this better still.