# Round-up of Scalaz type class instances for other libraries

Tags: java, scala, monads, scalaz, typeclass

I often find myself wanting (and then usually writing) [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) type class instances for classes in other Scala or Java libraries. To give just a few examples:

A monoid instance for [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `HList` gives you [monoid instances for case classes with appropriately typed members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439044/334519) almost for free.

An applicative functor instance for [Lift](http://liftweb.net/)'s `Box` allows you for example to sequence a list of boxes:

```
scala> val boxen: List[Box[Int]] = Full(1) :: Full(2) :: Full(3) :: Nil
boxen: List[net.liftweb.common.Box[Int]] = List(Full(1), Full(2), Full(3))

scala> boxen.sequence
res0: net.liftweb.common.Box[List[Int]] = Full(List(1, 2, 3))
```

A monad instance for [Dispatch 0.9](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)'s `Promise` (and `Promise[Either[Throwable, _]]`, etc.) is hugely useful for all kinds of things.

An [applicative functor instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7785762/334519) for the standard library's `Parser` makes applicative parsing more concise and elegant. (I just noticed that Scalaz 7 [now provides a monad instance for `Parser`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/util/parsing/combinator/Parser.scala).)

And so on...

These instances are almost always very general-purpose, and I'm sure lots of us have written lots of these lots of times. What I'm fishing for with this question is some kind of aggregator or clearinghouse for Scalaz type class instances. I'm not sure such a thing exists—I certainly haven't been able to find anything like it—but even just a collection of links to blog posts, GitHub repositories, or other resources would be useful to me.

I'd prefer Scalaz 7 instances, but I'll take anything I can get.

Comment: Vote to close because this question could not answered directly. Move it to the Scala mailing lists.

Comment: @sschaef: I'll admit I expected that response, and I agree that it's maybe close to the border, but I think it is a practical and answerable question, isn't likely to "solicit extended debate", etc. (Also I've contributed here more than on the Scalaz list, and was hoping to cash in on that.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be more useful as a repository on Github? Then users could collaborate on them and pull them into their own code more easily?

Comment: @MartinMcNulty: Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for—a link to something like that, or some things like that.

Comment: Gathering under an umbrella project might not be suitable, since different libs may differ in release rate. Making this a community wiki may be a good idea however.

Comment: Btw I wrote instances for Dispatch 0.9, but not published them yet. Not that they are too hard to write :)

Comment: @ron: I'd be more than happy for the question to be community wiki, too, but that option seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @ron: And right, most of these are pretty simple to write, but it still seems like a shame for all of us to keep writing them over and over.

Comment: @sschaef: I don't see the reason to close. There are tons of questions like this, "What are your top `N` favourite `xy`s for `de`f". Here `xy` = instances `de` = scalaz.

Comment: @TravisBrown I think I'm going to have to bite the bullet and add a dependency on Scalaz to shapeless (or at least a sub-project of some sort) so that we can do this properly. Head over to the shapeless mailing list and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Community wiki of Scalaz instances

#### Scalaz 7 instances

- Easy case class instances ([Monoid](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala), [Ordering](https://gist.github.com/3705819), possibly serialization and others) - [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)
- Play! 2 instances - [play-scalaz](https://github.com/teamon/play-scalaz) (Promise monad, Json serializers)
- Akka 2.x Future - [akkaz](https://github.com/robinp/akkaz)