# Wrapping a Monad into a parser - do I need Monad Transformers and how to do it?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

I have a monadic type `Exp` and I want to build a parser that parses into such a value. The following code works, but is there something nicer/cooler I can do?

```
def grid(x: Int, y: Int): Problem = ???
def expInt: Parser[Exp[Int]] = ???

def grid: Parser[Exp[Problem]] =
  for{
    ex ~ _ ~ ey <- "grid(" ~> expInt ~ "," ~ expInt <~ ")"
  } yield for{
    x <- ex
    y <- ey
  } yield grid(x,y)
```

I've heard of monad transformers, but still are a bit scared of Scalaz 7's wierd import system. Can someone answer whether

1. I can use monad transformers and
2. How this would look like in principle, using Scalaz 7 for a Scala combinator parser wrapping my own `Exp` Monad.

Comment: The question is, what benefits do you expect to get from the monad transformer in this case?

Comment: Maybe I don't have to write the second for-comprehension?

Comment: Ah, didn't see it, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First for the easy part—the "weird" import system:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
```

That's all. This will always work (barring name collisions, of course, but that's a possibility with any library and is easy to resolve), and nobody's going to look down on you for not using the new à la carte imports, which are mainly about documentation.

The basic pattern for monad transformers is that you have a `WhateverT[F[_], ...]` type class that has a method named `runWhateverT` (or just `run`) that returns an `F[Whatever[...]]`.

In this case it looks like you want to end up with a `Parser[Exp]`, which suggests that you need your own `ExpT[F[_]]` transformer. I won't start with details about how to implement this (which will depend on the semantics of your monad, of course), but will give an example using Scalaz's `OptionT`:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  implicit val monad = parserMonad(this)

  def oddNumber: OptionT[Parser, Int] = OptionT.optionT(
    "\\d+".r ^^ (_.toInt) ^^ (i => (i % 2 != 0) option i)
  )

  def pairOfOdds: OptionT[Parser, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- literal("(").liftM[OptionT]
    x <- oddNumber
    _ <- literal(",").liftM[OptionT]
    y <- oddNumber
    _ <- literal(")").liftM[OptionT]
  } yield (x, y)

  def apply(s: String) = parse(pairOfOdds.run, s)
}
```

See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7785762/334519) for some discussion about why we need the `implicit val monad = ...` line.

It works like this:

```
scala> MyParser("(13, 43)")
res0: MyParser.ParseResult[Option[(Int, Int)]] = [1.9] parsed: Some((13,43))

scala> MyParser("(13, 42)")
res1: MyParser.ParseResult[Option[(Int, Int)]] = [1.8] parsed: None
```

Note that `oddNumber.run` would give us a `Parser[Option[Int]]` that will parse a string of digits and return either a `Some(i)` (if they represent an odd number) or a `None` (if they're even).

We're not actually going to call `oddNumber.run`, though, in this case—the fact that we're using a monad transformer means that we can compose `oddNumber` with lifted `Parser` actions (the `literal(...)` here) in a single `for` comprehension.

The syntax here is ugly—we lose the nice `~` combinators and the implicit conversions from `String` to `Parser[String]`, for example, but we could easily write lifted versions of those things if we wanted.

Comment: So it's possible to get very close to my code, but without the second `for`? I will probably try this next week.

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement the monad transformer. But somehow I'm having trouble implementing `flatMap`. Also I observed, that in my use-cases the outer monad (Parser) is only used as a functor (only `map` is needed). Is it possible that I cannot implement a monad transformer for my type, but only something which is a functor when nested within a functor?